# My method is not returning anything in boolean when I am using string as a parameter in java

Tags: java, string, boolean

My method is not returning anything in boolean when I am using the String as a parameter in java.

```
public Boolean addTransaction(String branchName,String customerName,Double amountAdding)
{
    BranchName branchName1=findBranch(branchName);
    if(branchName1==null){
        System.out.println("No branch name");
        return branchName1.newTransactionAdd(customerName,amountAdding);
    }
    return false;
}

public Boolean addCustomer(String branchName,String customerName,Double PreviousDeposite)
{
    //let's check whether the name of customer is there or not
    BranchName branchName1=findBranch(branchName);
    if(branchName1==null){//if the name is not present than the object for BranchName will
        branchName1.AddnewCustomer(customerName,PreviousDeposite);
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You're using `branchName1` only when it's `null`...?

Comment: try using primitive type "boolean" instead of Boolean in your method returnType

Comment: What's the problem with the second method? Isn't it just the first, who doesn't return a boolean value, but null instead?

Answer (score 0):

In order for this line to return boolean

```
 return branchName1.newTransactionAdd(customerName,amountAdding);
```

`newTransactionAdd()` should also return boolean `true`, if I understand your code correctly.
Because what I think is happening is `newTransactionAdd(customerName,amountAdding)` in BranchName class is currently returns type `void`
Another option is

```
public Boolean addTransaction(String branchName,String customerName,Double    amountAdding)
{
    BranchName branchName1=findBranch(branchName);
    if(branchName1==null){
        System.out.println("No branch name");
        branchName1.newTransactionAdd(customerName,amountAdding);
        return true; //or what ever you want
    }
    return false;
}
```